# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable (When printing an integer and words)

Tags: python-3.x

```
#stage 2 dice rolling
#P1D1 means player ones dice one value and so on with P1D2
import random
print("player ones turn")
P1D1 = random.randint (1,6)
print ("your number is "(P1D1))
```

(this is in python 3.6.3)
when i run this piece of code it returns str object not callable
but when i run
print(P1D1) it seems to print the number without issue
anyone able to help thanks in advance

Comment: `"your number is "(P1D1)` attempts to call the string `"your number is "`

Comment: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: What value do you think (or intend) ``"your number is "(P1D1)`` evaluates to? Did you mean to use a format string such as ``f"your number is {P1D1}"`` perhaps? Note the different parentheses, and them being inside the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by your syntax on the last line. By putting the brackets right after a string it is like trying to call the string as a function, just like how putting brackets around `print`, it calls it. Try this.

```
print ("your number is ", P1D1)
```